# Как в цикле for Используя JavaScript вставить картинку?

Tags: javascript

Имеется JavaScript:

```js
var name = window.prompt('Добрый день видеть пожалуйста свое имя.');

if (!name) {
  window.alert('Работа окончена так как не Нивели свое имя');
  window.close();
} else {
  window.alert('Введите пожалуйста свою любимую цифру');
}

var x = window.prompt('Ваша придуманная цифра');

if (x) {
  window.alert('Спасибо вам за введённая вами цифру. Сейчас вы получите столько логотипов Какую цифру вы вели');
} else {
  window.alert('Очень жаль что вы не ввели вашу любимую цифру');
}
```

Как теперь показать с помощью функции `for` Столько логотипов и Какую цифру выбрал клиент?

Comment: Это что за сервис по раздаче грибов?

Comment: Там не про грибов а  логотипы,  просто сделал орфографическую ошибку.
Sorry,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var name = window.prompt('Добрый день видеть пожалуйста свое имя.');
if (!name) {
  window.alert('Работа окончена, так как не ввели свое имя');
  window.close();
} else {
  window.alert('Введите пожалуйста свою любимую цифру');
}
var x = window.prompt('Ваша придуманная цифра');
if (x && (typeof + x == 'number')) { // если значение введено и является числом
  window.alert('Спасибо вам за введённая вами цифру. Сейчас вы получите столько грибов Какую цифру вы вели');
  for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    document.getElementById('logos').innerHTML += '<img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/picture-frame-hanged-from-a-nail_318-67616.jpg" width="30" height="30" alt="" />'; // добавляем логотипы
  }
} else {
  window.alert('Очень жаль что вы не ввели вашу любимую цифру');
}
```

```html
<div id="logos"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо очень помогли